# Word wrapping programmatically isn't working as it should

Tags: swift, word-wrap

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell",     forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell


    myCell.textLabel?.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]
    myCell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lato", size: 18)
    myCell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    myCell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0



    return myCell
}
```

This is the block of code that I'm utilizing to change visual properties of my cell and I believe I should be getting line breaks/word wraps, but it cuts off regardless.

[image]

Comment: Something wrong with myCell.textLabel constraints or sizes. Be sure that size of label is equal to size of cell and constraints are right

Answer (score 0):

It's working as expected, just not yours.
The document says:

> ByWordWrapping
>   Wrapping occurs at word boundaries, **unless the
>   word itself doesn’t fit on a single line.** See [Characters and
>   Grapheme Clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008025) in [*String Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i) for a discussion of
>   issues related to determining word boundaries.
>
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

You can use `ByCharWrapping` instead. Or you should set the frame of your label accordingly.